# set autoplay option in existing owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I have a lot of trouble trying to set the autoPlay option on an existing owl-carousel(I mean not implemented by me) . it is part of a complicated wordpress theme :

my test url is at https://sprayfilm.fr/novo

I tried fiddling in the source code, with no success.

Is it possible to reconfigure a carousel after the fact ?

I tried a lot of things, but the only thing that prooved I even had access to the element was :

```
$('.owl-carousel').trigger( 'remove.owl.carousel', [0]);
```

that removes the first slide of the carousel, of course it's not what I want

I tried to reconfigure it like :

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
     items:1,
     loop:true,   
     autoPlay:1000            
});
```

but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.owl-carousel').trigger('owl.play',3000);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.